# (repository item button) I cant change cell individually?

Tags: c#, button, repository, devexpress

sorry for my english .

I use devexpress . I want to change the cell at the selected column , when I click the cell, opens a form and I select my data from there , after select  my data and click enter, my data coming to the cell but not individually , I mean all the cells in the column are changing . How can I change just my cell without anyother?

Here is my code :

```
private void repositoryItemButtonEdit1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TeklifFishSatirCinsiSec cinssec = new TeklifFishSatirCinsiSec();
    cinssec.ShowDialog();
    //  repositoryItemButtonEdit1.NullText = TeklifFishSatirCinsiSec.cinsi;
    //   repositoryItemButtonEdit2.NullText = TeklifFishSatirCinsiSec.code;
    //   repositoryItemButtonEdit2.Buttons[0].Caption = TeklifFishSatirCinsiSec.cinsi;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is expected that your changes affect every cell, because you are modifying a single instance shared between all the cells.

If you need to display different editors (even of the same type but with different settings applied), use the [CustomCellEdit](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraPivotGridPivotGridControl_CustomCellEdittopic) event of the GridView.

Since you allow users to specify settings to each cell individually, you will need to store repository items in a associative alist (Dictionary or Hashtable) where a [datasource row index](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_GetDataSourceRowIndextopic) and the column's field name should be used as key.

Do not use row handles as keys, because they depend on sorting, filtering and grouping applied.